# How to use Query with variables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a Table with Two columns - Case (string) and DateTime.
I want to use a query that will show Case and number of minutes between last case, for every case.

For example, my table:

```
   Case                 Date
1/15548569       01/01/2015 10-00-00  
1/15548570       01/01/2015 10-15-00 
1/15548571       01/01/2015 10-28-00
```

Query result:

```
1/15548569 0 Minutes
1/15548570 15 Minutes
1/15548571 13 Minutes
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option with `lag`:

```
select [case],
  [date],
  cast([date]-lag([date]) over (order by [date]) as time) as diff
from yourtable
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e9f7/2)